# Why is the word cigarette not punctuated -cigarètte- because of the last muted -e-?

Tags: écriture

Why is the word cigarette not punctuated having an `e` preceding a muted `e`, is it because its origin?

For example,

célèbre

Comment: You mean accent, not punctuated.

Comment: Because the letter "e" is pronounced" as "é" when in front of a double consonant, it's a rule.

Comment: The question could be : "why does *célèbre* require an accent on the second e?" That's the tricky one. The case with double consonnant is the easy one : no accent written, but pronounced as an *è*.

Comment: @XouDo *célèbre* is easy too: an accent written so pronounced as is.

Comment: @jlliagre It's tricky to understand why there should a è written in célèbre, before two consonnants.

Comment: @XouDo  Two consonants ≠ a double consonant.

Comment: @jlliagre Ok, mais dans *sélection*, *ct* n'est pas une double consonne, pourtant, pas d'accent! Si j'ai bien compris c'est une question de découpage des syllabes, mais le moins qu'on puisse dire c'est assez obscure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In words in *-elle*, *-ette*, *-esse*, *-erre* and *-enne*, the first *e* is pronounced *è*.

A few examples:

> vaisselle, cachette, délicatesse, serre, antenne

So *cigarette* is perfectly regular and doesn't need an accent.